# Windows 8 start screen, making scrolling position stick?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

One thing I hated the most about Windows 8 is that I have to scroll the Start Screen to the right each time I press Win to start a program.

Often times I try to launch 2 or 3 apps together, and they are all in the same position. I have to scroll to right each time to find them. Is there a setting that could make scrolling position stick?

Comment: You can try searching instead. Press your Windows-key and start typing the name of the application and it should come up instantly. Sorry, but I am not aware of any apps allow you to change the default start position for the tiles.

Comment: Can't believe this is what I have to do. It's a lot of typing and clicks. At least back then we have the quick launch, and frequency based start menu....

Comment: You can try a 3rd party application which will give you something like a start menu where you can pin your most frequently used apps. Check the third point of my answer here (http://superuser.com/questions/543003/asus-k75d-windows-8-install-windows-7/543015#543015).

Comment: @sabrefresco, thanks. Pokki looked nice. I still can't believe Microsoft released this thing.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.Alternatively On start screen, Try `Ctrl`+`-` then use the Arrow key, it will give you easier and less time consuming way to get to required program. One thing I often use is `Page-Up` and `Page-Down` to move on Modern Start Screen, it is much faster.

Comment: the best practice approach imho is to put Apps/Icons you often need to the left side of the start menu... i mean thats basically what you did in win7 putting often used apps in places where you can access them easier. and btw: win-key followed by typing the app-name might be a lot of keyboard-clicks but is usually way quicker than doing it all by mouse

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to change the default scroll location of the Start screen. It will always start at a "home position" which is the leftmost side of the screen.

You can always move the items you use the most frequently into a group and place that group closer to the left hand side to eliminate scrolling.

In response to the Quick Launch, you can still pin items to the task bar on the legacy Windows screen.